# When validating a form submission, allow any character

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

Currently I am running script in php to allow a submission of a file if the username is 'valid' i.e. only uses characters and numbers. If this is not the case the user is returned to the url with an error message within the url saying 'invalidusername'.

I tried to mimic this script with a feature on my website that allowed people to upload a form to the website as long as the 'title' was valid i.e. had just numbers and characters just as the username did. But, I have realised in a title I actually want to enable all characters to be able to be used in the title. Should I just delete the script? Or, is there a way to allow `preg_match()` to enable all characters. I have tried php scripts online but it has not worked. My code is below:

```
if (empty($author) || empty($title) || empty($year) || empty($url) || empty($keywords)) {
    header("Location: ../upload.php?error=emptyfields");
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $title) && !filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    header("Location: ../upload.php?error=invalidtitleurl");
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $title)) {
    header("Location: ../upload.php?error=invalidtitle");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Please do add your expected result along with your input. It'll help.

Comment: `[\s\S]` matches **all** characters.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of tips:

1. When you find yourself wanting to use `preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", ...)` to match string that are comprised solely of alphanumeric characters (and the string cannot be empty), you should use the non-regex equivalent `ctype_alnum()`.
2. If you are not validating the quality of the `title` submission, but just that the value has a positive length.  You can use the `isset()` function (or the null coalescing operator) to ensure that the element exists then use `strlen()` to ensure that the value has more than one character.
3. In php, `else if` should be a single word to comply with [PSR-12 coding standards](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/).
4. The trouble with using `empty()`, is that if someone submits the string value of zero, then `empty()` will deny/redirect their submission because  `empty('0') === true`.  Is this a fringe case?  Yes, but you don't want to be irritating your users if they are not doing the wrong thing.  A user with the username `0` will be encountering a lot of difficulty with your site, if you are using `empty()` in all validation checks.  Food for thought.